# How to set asp panel height using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have problem on setting the height of asp panel using javascript. I used below code to do this but didn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
  var sheight = $(window).height();
  $("#paneldata").height(sheight-240);
  });
</script>
```

What must be the problem with my code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that **asp.net has server side controls** then get **target id** this way(and fix other issue also as shown below) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
  var sheight = $(window).height();
  $("#<%=paneldata.ClientID %>").height((sheight-240) + "px");
  });
</script>
```

OR(If you are using ClientID in Static Mode) then try this only :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
    var sheight = $(window).height();
    $("#paneldata").height((sheight-240) + "px"); // add 'px' with height as shown here
   });
 </script>
```

Comment: It would have been better to ask OP for clarification. As if OP is using ClientID in `Static` Mode then your answer is of no value

Comment: @Satpal..the questioner has not posted anything except jquery code so i think the problem of id can be there as shown in my answer.

Comment: @Kartikeya...Ok, it works perfect sir..i just forgot to put 'px'..Thanks for the perfect answer :-)